# Jenkins pre build (and post SCM checkout) step?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Is there a plugin or method for doing a pre build step on a Jenkins build (MSBuild specifically)? I found a couple similar questions on SO and other places, but they all wanted the step pre SCM checkout too, so I couldn't find anything for my specific case.

I need my step after SCM checkout, but before the build. If you're curious, it's a "nuget.exe restore" call that I was just going to throw in a script or something. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it buried in a nuget automatic package restore tutorial.

In the build section of a Jenkins project there is an option to "Add build step". There is no icon indicating you can do so, but you actually can then simply DRAG that build step above your actual build section. This will be a pre-build step.